# Use Sublime Javatar package for Groovy code?

Tags: groovy, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Can the Sublime Text 3 [Javatar package/plugin](https://github.com/spywhere/Javatar) be used for *.groovy source code? Would you give me the steps?

Also, I want to use the prerelease version of the package but after adding its name to pre-release setting I don't know how to get the prerelease version via Package Control. I just see version 1.X still.

```
"install_prereleases":
[
    "Javatar"
]
```

Comment: `Can the Sublime Text 3 Javatar package/plugin be used for *.groovy source code?` - Do you mean `javatar` to compile and execute groovy code?

Comment: No but how do I set that up? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the Sublime Text 3 Javatar package/plugin be used for *.groovy source code?

No... see https://github.com/spywhere/Javatar/issues/3

Comment: Thanks Tim. Then can you also answer my next question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795968/setup-sublime-text-3-for-groovy-coding

Comment: @VahidPazirandeh please don't badger people to answer your other questions - it's considered rather rude on this site.

Comment: Sorry about that @Matt

Comment: What I meant to say before the Enter key cut me short: Yes sorry about that @MattDMo, it is only that Tim has answered several of my questions in the past so I felt comfortable asking him that. Cheers my friend